# A question related to @property

Tags: iphone

why we are using nonatomic in the @ property
@property(nonatomic,retain)UIButton *button;

what is the meaning of nonatomic?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `nonatomic` modifier means that the property isn't locked when it is accessed or modified from multiple threads. You can find out more in [this Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588866/objective-c-properties-atomic-vs-nonatomic).